# The Standard Model and $U(1) \times SU(2) \times SU(3)$ symmetry

Tags: standard-model, group-theory

It's common to see the standard model referred to as a $U(1)\times SU(2)\times SU(3)$ symmetric theory. This seems to me to be a bit of over-generalization and poetic license since only the quark field transforms under all three groups. The chiral lepton fields, for instance, carry no $SU(3)$ indices at all, nor do the three EW bosons, while the gluon field has no weak hypercharge nor weak isospin components. Are there additional facts that put that statement on solid ground mathematically?

Comment: Leptons do transform under $\mathrm{SU}(3)$; they do so trivially, but the trivial representation is just as good as the fundamental one. The SM truly is a $\mathrm U(1)\times\mathrm{SU}(2)\times\mathrm{SU}(3)$ gauge theory; some fields just happen transform more complicatedly than others under each factor.

Comment: Does the U(1)xSU(2)xSU(3) really reflect all three generations of fermions in the SM? I've been given the impression that it does not.

Comment: It's not the job of the gauge group to tell you what fermions there are. You define a gauge theory by first specifying the gauge group, and then how the various fields transform under the gauge group. What a "standard model generation" is, and that there are three of them, belongs to that second step.

Comment: I'm speaking of the gauge group that defines the *local* gauge symmetry that determines the gauge force fields. Global symmetries *will* depend on the fermion content.

Comment: The gauge group gives what rules you have for interactions. The group strictly defines the gauge bosons but doesn't restrict the number of fermions or generations uniquely. Nevertheless, Grand Unified Theories try to find a group that, in the way, could also contain all the fermions in one multiplet since it would make the parameter space smaller. Side note: the actual gauge group of SM is $SU(3)_c \times SU(2)_L \times U(1)_Y \, / \, \mathbb{Z}_6$, which is smaller (less symmetry).  See: Baker *et al.* (Phys. Lett. B583, 379) and Carroll *et al.* (Phys.Rev. D50 (1994) 2806-2818) for details.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform ...that's an answer.

Comment: If we admit the trivial or singlet "transformation" of the fields then, since all the fields transform trivially (i.e. do not transform at all) under all the higher SU(n) groups we can say that the SM is a U(1) x SU(2) x SU(3) x SU(4) x SU(5) x SU(6) x SU(7) x ...  Theory, but that is not done.  Still looking for a better answer to the original question.